# How can I define empty session in mvc view, c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I have define and empty `session` inside the view like this

```
<input id="myc" type="hidden" data-value="@Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["Ealert"].ToString()" />
```

but when I run, it says **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

I have no idea.in my controller I do like this

```
Session["Ealert"] = null;

            Random random = new Random();
            int idONe = random.Next(99,999);
            int idTwo = random.Next(999, 9999);
            string middle = "menuka";

            string fullID = idONe.ToString() + middle + idTwo.ToString();

            var N_ID = fullID;
            var N_Email = N_EmailAdd;



            TourCenterDBEntities NewsLetterEntities = new TourCenterDBEntities();

            var existing = NewsLetterEntities.News_Letter.Where(l => l.N_Email == N_EmailAdd);
            Debug.WriteLine(existing.Count());

            if(existing.Count()==0)
            {
                News_Letter NewsLetterDetails = new News_Letter();



                NewsLetterDetails.N_id = N_ID;
                NewsLetterDetails.N_Email = N_Email;

                NewsLetterEntities.News_Letter.Add(NewsLetterDetails);

                NewsLetterEntities.SaveChanges();

                Session["Ealert"] = "s";
            }
            else
            {
                Session["Ealert"] = "e";


            }


            return Json(new { });
```

how can I do it.hope your help with this.i'm full of stuck.

Comment: Your method appears to be returning a JSON result with `return Json(new { });`, but nothing is actually in that result.

Comment: Why? MVC was designed to be sessionless, only use it if you really have to use it. I see no good reason above to use the Session object at all.

Comment: what is the purpose you want to achieve ??

Comment: so what can I do for it. What I'm really going to do is if record exists show error message and if not show success message in the view.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the object reference error, in your controller or your view? If it's the controller code, which line is the error thrown on?

Answer (score 0):

ok try this

```
@if(Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["Ealert"]!=null)
{
<input id="myc" type="hidden" data-value="@Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["Ealert"].ToString()" />

}
```

Comment: you cannot use an unsigned session as it is an object ...
what is your hidden field doing ??

Comment: @if(Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session["Ealert"]!=null)
{
<script>
alert('aaaa');
</script>
}

Comment: replace this if condition it will show an alert and when are you assigning your session ? in your post or get method ?